# JavaScript loop through array, multiply price property by 2

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm trying to loop through `amusementRides` in the `doublePrices` function below, multiplying the price by 2 but I get nothing in return. What am I missing?

```
var amusementRides = [  
   {  
      id:'A1',
      name:'superman',
      price:12,
      opening_dates:[  
         'Monday',
         'Tuesday',
         'Wednesday',
         'Thursday',
         'Friday',
         'Saturday',
         'Sunday'
      ],
      children_access:false
   },
   {  
      id:'A2',
      name:'raging bull',
      price:10,
      opening_dates:[  
         'Saturday',
         'Sunday'
      ],
      children_access:false
   },
   {  
      id:'A3',
      name:'teacups',
      price:7,
      opening_dates:[  
         'Friday',
         'Saturday',
         'Sunday'
      ],
      children_access:true
   }
];

// Define variable
var amusementRidesDouble = doublePrices(amusementRides);

// Define function to multiply price by 2
function doublePrices(amusementRides) {

    for (var price in amusementRides) {
        if amusementRides.hasOwnProperty(price) {
            alert (price *= 2);
    }
}
}

console.log(amusementRidesDouble);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `price` isn't really the price, they are indexes of `amusementRides`.

Comment: Return the `amusementRides` from function.

Answer (score 3):

You can use map function of array and update required fields

```
function doublePrices(amusementRides) {
    amusementRidesdouble = amusementRides.map(function(item){
        item.price = 2 * item.price;
        return item;
   })
   return amusementRidesdouble;

}
```

Comment: Thanks! The exercise I'm going through forces us to use the `doublePrices` function, so I can't use the map function within the amusementRidesdouble variable.

Comment: You can simply wrap it into that function

Comment: One follow up question:

If I had to create a second function: `debugAmusementRides()`
which would loop through the list of attractions 
and write the name and the new price for each item to the console, how would I go about that?

Answer (score 1):

`amusementRides` is an array, it is not defined as key values

change the method to

```
for (var counter = 0; counter < amusementRides.length; counter++) 
  {
     if (amusementRides[counter].price) 
       {
            alert (amusementRides[counter].price * 2);
            amusementRides[counter].price *= 2;
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

A good approach would be:

```
var doublePrices = function( data ) {
    data.forEach( function( item ) {
        item.price *= 2;
    }
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should avoid for-in loop with array

you can use forEach:

```
amusementRides.forEach(function(item) {
  item.price *= 2;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i=0; i<amusementRides.length; i++) { 
amusementRides[i].price*=2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only mistake in your code is you have tried to foreach loop like in C#. In Javascript you can't do that way.

You can modify your code like below.

```
for ( var i=0;i<amusementRides.length;i++) {
    var price=amusementRides[i];
        alert (price *= 2);
}
```

But the best approach will be :

```
amusementRides = amusementRides.forEach( function( item ) {
                 item.price *= 2;
              }
```